# Android: custom views with proportional widths and same heights

Tags: android, user-interface, widget, color-picker

I try to implement a good reusable color picker for my Sketcher application. Instructions and screenshots are here: http://bit.ly/sketcherapp

The problem is I'm stuck with a good "resizable" UI which enable me to support wide range of devices with different screen sizes.

[image]

The top two widgets should be the same height and have proportional widths: 80 to 20. Also it would be nice to specify paddings in XML.

Current implementation is not good. I hardcoded some values into code and also it looks bad on Xoom devices because of inaccurate layout measurements.

Is there any way to implement this behavior? Ideally, I need some way to do it like with HTML tables (pseudocode):

```
table.width=100%, td1.width=80%, td2.padding=5px, ...
```

or something like that.

Current implementation:

- code:
  https://github.com/wargoth/Sketcher/tree/master/src/org/sketcher/colorpicker
- layout:
  https://github.com/wargoth/Sketcher/blob/master/res/layout/color_picker.xml

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I stopped boring with it and created dedicated layouts for each screen size.

Answer (score 2):

> The top two widgets should be the same height and have proportional widths: 80 to 20.

Use a horizontal `LinearLayout`, `android:layout_width="0dip"` for both widgets, and `android:layout_weight="80"` and `android:layout_weight="20"`, respectively.

> Also it would be nice to specify paddings in XML.

Use `android:paddingLeft` and kin.